# How to avoid Rollbacking after Catching EJB Rollbacked ApplicationException?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

We are facing a scenario similar to the following:

```
@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
class UniqueConstraintViolated extends RuntimeException { ... }

interface GenericStorageService {
  void insert(Object ety); // throws UniqueConstraintViolation
}

class ServiceA {
  @Inject GenericStorageService store;

  void insert(A ety) {
    someSideEffect();
    store.insert(ety);
    someOtherSideEffect();
  }
}

class ServiceB {
  @Inject GenericStorageService store;

  void insertIfNotYetPresent(B ety) {
    try {        
      someSideEffect();
      store.insert(ety);
      someOtherSideEffect();
    } catch (UniqueConstraintViolation e) {
      // that's totally ok
    }
  }
}
```

In this scenario,

- It is an actual user error to request the insertion of some `A` that was previously inserted. The transaction cannot be committed in a meaningful way.
- It is *not* an error to request the insertion of some `B` that was previously existed. The transaction can be safely committed by simply acknowledging the existence of said `B`. In particular, the side effects need to be committed regardless of whether the given `B` was inserted before or not.

According to (my understanding of) the EJB specification, the above code would trigger a **rollback in either case**, not leading to the desired semantics.

As I understand, EJB leaves us with the following options:

1. Decorate `UniqueConstraintViolated` with `rollback = false`, manually catch it in `ServiceA` and rollback the transaction via programmatic transaction control.
2. Split `UniqueConstraintViolated` into two siblings `UniqueConstraintViolatedThatNeedsRollback` and `UniqueConstraintViolatedThatNeedsNoRollback`. Further, replacing `GenericStorageService`'s `insert` Method by two variants `insertWithRollbackingUniqueConstraint` and `insertWithNonRollbackingUniqueConstraint`.
3. Just suck it.

Option 1 is undesirable since the majority of services is of the same type as`ServiceA`, so `rollback = true` is the more accurate choice. Also, it voids the elegance of declarative transaction control.

Option 2 is undesirable since to `GenericStorageService`, the two cases are really the same. A distinction at this level does not make sense. Furthermore, `UniqueConstraintViolated` is not the only exception that would need a distinction... we'd suffer from a combinatoric explosion.

Option 3 needs no further explanation.

This leaves me with the final question:

**What is option 4?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally my work around, for option2.

```
//So generic transaction service, that commits every transaction in a different transaction context.
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
public class TransactionalService {

   public void executeTransactional(final Runnable task) {
     task.run();
   }
}

@Statless
public class ServiceB {

  @Inject GenericStorageService store;
  @Inject TransactionalService transactionalService;

  public void insertIfNotYetPresent(B ety) {
    try {       
      transactionalService.executeTransactional(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            store.insert(ety);
         }
      };

      transactionalService.executeTransactional(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            someSideEffect();
         }
      };

    } catch (UniqueConstraintViolation e) {
      // that's totally ok
    }
  }
}
```

//If you are in java 8, very much simple, all the verbose is gone

```
@Statless
public class ServiceB {

  @Inject GenericStorageService store;
  @Inject TransactionalService transactionalService;

  public void insertIfNotYetPresent(B ety) {
    try {   
      transactionalService.executeTransactional(() -> store.insert(ety) ); 
      transactionalService.executeTransactional(() -> someSideEffect() );

    } catch (UniqueConstraintViolation e) {
      // that's totally ok
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I slightly changed my problem by adding a call to `someOtherSideEffect()`. How do we apply your workaround to this altered case? We need to ensure that `someSideEffect()` and `someOtherSideEffect()` are run in the same transaction.

Comment: In same transaction, forget about it. unless you implement the manual handling of the exception. EJB specs clearly states that if an exception has been thrown, the transaction is aborted

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. Thanks for confirming my understanding!